# creating an http request in android it get stopped and the application force close

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use HTTP request on android with JSON and php/mysql to display some data from the mysql database .

the application is simply push a button and it will display in the log cat the selected data from the database and it display the second page on the emulator using intent..

the problem is that when i try to run the application the system crush before it send the request to the http and i use a localhost server (wamp) so the URL i used is: http://**10.0.2.2/studentservice/StudentService/getStudentByID.php**

after i push the button this is the

## logCat

```
10-15 14:07:28.160: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:28.320: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:07:28.630: D/gralloc_goldfish(854): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-15 14:07:28.660: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:28.670: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:07:35.800: E/Error befor http(854): Error before the http request
10-15 14:07:36.210: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:36.230: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:07:36.730: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:36.750: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:07:37.250: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:37.270: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:07:37.770: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:37.780: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:07:38.281: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:38.300: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:07:38.800: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:38.821: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:07:48.400: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:07:48.460: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:10:25.630: I/dalvikvm(854): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:10:25.650: I/dalvikvm(854): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

## after it crush the log cat display

```
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lebdev.fitguide.activities/com.lebdev.fitguide.activities.SecondaryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.lebdev.fitguide.controller.HttpManager.getResponseFromURL(HttpManager.java:70)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.lebdev.fitguide.activities.SecondaryActivity.onCreate(SecondaryActivity.java:54)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  ... 11 more
10-15 14:35:14.341: I/dalvikvm(906): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-15 14:35:14.370: I/dalvikvm(906): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

## MainActivity

```
package com.lebdev.fitguide.activities;

import com.lebdev.fitguide.businessModel.Student;
import com.lebdev.fitguide.businessModel.Subject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtMessage;
    TextView lblMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Onclick_btnSend(View v) {

         Intent intent  = new Intent(this, SecondaryActivity.class);
         //intent.putExtra("message", txtMessage.getText().toString());
         Student std = new Student(txtMessage.getText().toString(),1234, 1);
         std.getSubjects().add(new Subject("itc", 5));
         intent.putExtra("Student", std);
         startActivity(intent);

         Toast.makeText(this, "i am sending a message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

## JsonObjectMapper

```
package com.lebdev.fitguide.om;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

import com.lebdev.fitguide.businessModel.Student;

public class JsonObjectMapper {

    public static Student jsonToStudent(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        Student std = null;

        try {

            std = new Student(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                    .getJSONObject(0).getString("Name"),
                    Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                            .getJSONObject(0).getString("index")),
                    Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                            .getJSONObject(0).getString("ID")));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error Json Converter", ex.getMessage());
        }

        return std;
    }

    public static List<Student> jsonToStudentList(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        List<Student> stdList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student").length(); i++) {

                stdList.add(new Student(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                        .getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"), Integer
                        .parseInt(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                                .getJSONObject(i).getString("index")), Integer
                        .parseInt(jsonObject.getJSONArray("Student")
                                .getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"))));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("Error Json Converter", ex.getMessage());
        }

        return stdList;
    }
}
```

## SecondaryObject

```
package com.lebdev.fitguide.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.lebdev.fitguide.businessModel.Student;
import com.lebdev.fitguide.controller.HttpManager;
import com.lebdev.fitguide.controller.JSONParser;
import com.lebdev.fitguide.om.JsonObjectMapper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondaryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid", "2"));

        Log.e("Error befor http", "Error before the http request");
        JSONObject jsonObj = JSONParser
                .parseJSONFromString(new HttpManager()
                        .getResponseFromURL(
                                "http://10.0.2.2/studentservice/StudentService/getStudentByID.php",
                                params));

        Log.e("Error after http", "Error after the http request");

        Student std = JsonObjectMapper.jsonToStudent(jsonObj);

        Log.e("STUDENT DATA", "ID:" + std.getID() +     "Name:" + std.getName()
                + "Index: " + std.getIndex());
/*
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            TextView lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSentMessage);
            Student student = bundle.getParcelable("Student");

            lblMessage.setText("I 've recieved a student with a name "
                    + student.getName() + " and has a Subject "
                    + student.getSubjects().get(0).getName() + " with a grade "
                    + student.getSubjects().get(0).getGrade());
        }
*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secondary, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post LogCat and google your exception!

Answer (score 0):

`10-15 14:35:13.781: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.lebdev.fitguide.controller.HttpManager.getResponseFromURL(HttpManager.java:70)`

That's a pointer to your code, line number and all, about where the null pointer (null message to Log.e() ) is coming from and causing the crash.

That's obvious from your logcat, so you're doing something in

`JSONObject jsonObj = JSONParser
                .parseJSONFromString(new HttpManager()
                        .getResponseFromURL(
                                "http://10.0.2.2/studentservice/StudentService/getStudentByID.php",
                                params));`

That's causing a null msg written to Log.e().